# See the window of a batch file that I start from IIS ASP.NET WebAPI thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, process

In my project I need to start a batch file from a thread on the server and wait for it to finish. My code is:

```
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = batchFilePath;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-0";
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

and in the batch is simply put "pause".
The problem is that is don't see any window open and the thread is stuck and wait for the batch to finish.Only when I close the process by the windows task manager the program continues. The problem happens also if I put in the batch "cmd". How can I see the window? I want to make sure that the batch is running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a batch file running on the server?  And you are not logged into the server, but into a web client?

You won't be able to see the console window from a web client, because it's running on a different machine.

If you *are* logged into the server, but still aren't seeing the window, you could try researching and experimenting with the `ProcessStartInfo` properties `CreateNoWindow` or `UseShellExecute`.

You might also want to look into `RedirectStandardInput` and `RedirectStandardOutput` if you need to see (or inspect programmatically) what the process writes to the console window.

Comment: I need to set `UseShellExecute` to true because it is a file with the extension `.bat` . Finally I managed to see that the batch worked by creating file in the batch.But it is still interesting how you can see the window if you write in the batch commands like `cmd` or `pasue`.